# How to get JScrollPanes within a JScrollPane to follow parent's resizing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

So I have a bunch of `JTable`s. Each `JTable` is inside a `JScrollPane`. I'm then adding each of these `JScrollPane`s to a `JPanel`. I'm then adding this `JPanel` to a `JScrollPane` then that to another `JPanel` with `BorderLayout`. The larger `JScrollPane` properly resizes with its parent, but each of the smaller `JScrollPane`s have constant height, which is larger than the window when it is small. How can I get each of the children `JScrollPane`s to resize with the height of the window/their parent?

I've tried adding more intermediary `JPanel`s with `FlowLayout`, `BorderLayout`, and nothing seems to work.

Here's some relevant code:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    public MyPanel()
    {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            // View extends JTable
            panel.add(new JScrollPane(new View(new Model())));
        }
        add(new JScrollPane(panel));
    }
}
```

I'm really just trying to get a bunch of tables with scrollbars horizontally next to each other inside a larger panel with a horizontal scrollbar. And I want all that stuff to resize appropriately when the window size changes.

more code:

```
final MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
final JTabbedPane tabView = new JTabbedPane();
tabView.add(...);
tabView.add("foo", panel);

final JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, ..., tabView);
this.add(splitPane); // this extends JFrame
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the JScrollPane that's not resizing? It could be the parent JPanel. Try `add(new JScrollPane(panel), BorderLayout.CENTER);`, should work. Also for troubleshooting Swing components, setting a background color tends to help find the problematic component.

Comment: That didn't change anything. I believe the default of the BorderLayout is BorderLayout.CENTER.

Comment: The best way of getting a decent quick answer is by creating and posting a decent [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Can you post the code where you add a MyPanel to a JFrame?

Comment: Posted. @HovercraftFullOfEels believe me this is the short version.

Comment: @arasmussen: but it's neither compilable nor runnable. If you don't get a decent answer soon, you may want to read the link to see the details. Again it's [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I don't see how I could post a compileable example of JTables inside JScrollPanes inside a JPanel inside a JScrollPane inside a JPanel and keep it short at the same time.

Comment: You could if the JTables all use the same dummy data. No one is requiring you to do this of course, so it's up to you, but my experience here is that it helps much if we can see the code, run the code, experience the problem, manipulate the code, and solve the problem. The longer the program, the harder it is for us to quickly understand it of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html). If you want the opposite: some table being fixed, you can wrap it with constraint [Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100, 100))](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html) .