# How to get a JScrollPane to resize with its parent JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, miglayout

My question is similar to this one ([How to get JScrollPanes within a JScrollPane to follow parent's resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457900/how-to-get-jscrollpanes-within-a-jscrollpane-to-follow-parents-resizing)), but that question wasn't clear and the answer there didn't help me..

I have this SSCCE (using [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)):

```
public static final int pref_height = 500;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
    innerPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 5));

    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setColumns(20);
        textArea.setRows(5);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        innerPanel.add(new JLabel("Notes" + i));
        innerPanel.add(jsp, "span, grow");
    }
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(innerPanel) {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            Dimension dim = new Dimension(super.getPreferredSize().width + getVerticalScrollBar().getSize().width, pref_height);
            setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            return dim;
        }
    };
    jsp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.green, 5));

    JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
    outerPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 5));
    outerPanel.add(jsp);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JDesktopPane jdp = new JDesktopPane();
    frame.add(jdp);
    jdp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.pack();

    JInternalFrame jif = new JInternalFrame("Title", true, true, true, true);
    jif.pack();
    jif.add(outerPanel);

    jdp.add(jif);
    jif.pack();
    jif.setVisible(true);


    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

I want the `JScrollPane` to resize whenever the parent `JPanel` is resized. Basically, I want the green border to line up with the red border. Right now, the green border stays the same size no matter the red border (unless you resize too small).

Comment: search in answers tagged by miglayout by @kleopatra (JScrollPane + whatever inside)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
```

A JPanel uses a FlowLayout by default which always respects the size of the component added to it. As a guess, maybe you can use:

```
JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
```

A `BorderLayout` give all the space available to the component added to the panel. By default a JInternalFrame also uses a BorderLayout. So since all the parent components of your scroll pane use a BorderLayout all the space should go to the scroll pane.

When you post a SSCCE you should post code using classes from the JDK that simulates your problem so that everybody can test your SSCCE.

Comment: Yes, I realized at the last minute my SSCCE had `MigLayout`, but I'm struggling getting these hand-coded GUI APIs to bend to my whims. So I didn't bother trying without it...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this did not have an answer that uses the original layout so here is one.

In order to make the `JScrollPane` resize when the parent `JPanel` is resized you need to do two things.

**1)** Set the layout of the panel to grow. This can be using the following code.

```
new MigLayout("",  //Layout Constraints
    "grow",        //Column Constraints
    "grow");       //Row Constraints
```

**2)** Set the component to grow. This is as simple as adding an extra argument in the `add()` function.

```
add(jsp, "grow");
```

**Extra**
In order to make the `JTextArea` column grow when you resize the `JScrollPane` you can change the layout to only make the second column change. For example

```
new MigLayout("",                        //Layout Constraints
    "[/*Column 1*/][grow /*Column 2*/]", //Column Constraints
    "");                                 //Row Constraints
```

Also, I would recommend you use `wrap` instead of `span` to use the next row as `span` refers using so many columns. For example `span 2 //Means use 2 columns for this component`. This would mean when you add your `jsp` to `innerPanel` it would become

```
innerPanel.add(jsp, "wrap, grow");
```

**Edited SSSCE**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class JSPR extends JFrame {
    public static final int pref_height = 500;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "[][grow]", ""));
        innerPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 5));

        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
            textArea.setColumns(20);
            textArea.setRows(5);
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            textArea.setLineWrap(true);
            JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(textArea);

            innerPanel.add(new JLabel("Notes" + i));
            innerPanel.add(jsp, "wrap, grow");
        }
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(innerPanel) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                Dimension dim = new Dimension(super.getPreferredSize().width + getVerticalScrollBar().getSize().width, pref_height);
                setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                return dim;
            }
        };
        jsp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.green, 5));

        JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "grow", "grow"));
        outerPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 5));
        outerPanel.add(jsp, "grow");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JDesktopPane jdp = new JDesktopPane();
        frame.add(jdp);
        jdp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.pack();

        JInternalFrame jif = new JInternalFrame("Title", true, true, true, true);
        jif.pack();
        jif.add(outerPanel);

        jdp.add(jif);
        jif.pack();
        jif.setVisible(true);


        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```